# Angular - combining Observables with promise

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, promise, observable, angularfire2

Currently, I am calling the database to extract all the conversations of a specific user. After that, I am looping through those conversations and I extract metadata such as message text, message sender and etc from each conversation.
I create an object for each with its' metadata which then are all stored in an Array - in my case `this.recentChats`.

```
this.af.getObservable(`userChats/${this.userID}/`).pipe(
  // we map the array of conversations to an array of the (before inner) observables

  map(recentConversations =>
    recentConversations.map(conversation =>
      this.af.getObservableSortByVar(`allChats/${conversation.conversationID}/`, 'lastUpdate'))),

  // combine the observables. will emit a new value of ALL conversation data when one of the conversations changes

  switchMap(recentConversations => combineLatest(recentConversations)),
  // map each conversation to the conversation object 
  map(conversations =>
    conversations.map(conversationData => {
      let userKey, lastMessage, lastMessageText, lastMessageSender, lastMessageDate;

      for (let i = 0; conversationData.length > i; i++) {
        switch (conversationData[i].key) {
          case 'messages': {
            lastMessage = (conversationData[i][Object.keys(conversationData[i])[Object.keys(conversationData[i]).length - 1]]);
            lastMessageText = lastMessage.message;
            lastMessageSender = lastMessage.sender;
            lastMessageDate = lastMessage.date;
          }
          case 'users': {
            userKey = conversationData[i].userKey;
          }
        }
      }
      return this.createConversationObject('username', userKey, lastMessageSender, lastMessageText, lastMessageDate);
    }))
).subscribe(recentChats => this.recentChats = recentChats);
```

However, on the line where `return this.createConversationObject('username', ...)` is called, I have been struggling to assign a user's actual username, fetched from the database.

Basically, I am using the `userKey` local variable, which is obtained from the switch-case code above, in order to attempt to do the following:

```
let tempUsername;
this.af.getUserName(userKey).then((username) => {
   tempUsername = username;
}
```

And then pass the `tempUsername` in the return statement. However, I have been struggling with making the result would to be awaited - in order for the username to be fetched, before the return is called.

Does anyone have any suggestions how can I properly achieve the desired result?

Comment: is `this.af.getObservableSortByVar()` returning an `Observable` as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit (after understanding the issue more closely)**

Here's the code example for the proposed solution: [Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-rxjs-convert-promise-to-observable)

Here are the modification that needs to be done to your code:

- In the `map(conversations =>` block, return the  modified object with `userkey` appended and not the results of `this.createConversationObject()`
- introduce `switchMap` after this and convert the Promise to Observable using `rxjs -> from` operator, also convert the results of the updated object returned from the previous `map` operation into a new Observable using `rxjs -> of` operators
- now return the result of `CombineLatest(OriginalObservable, fromPromiseObservable)`
- lastly you further need to map the results of these two Observable returns into one of use it directly in your call to `this.createConversationObject()`
- and finally you can subscribe to the result to get the actual result as a final step

Hope this clarifies!

**Original response**

Here's my suggestion:

- You could convert `this.af.getUserName(userKey)` promise to an observable first by using `fromPromise` provided by rxjs.
- and then use this converted observable for username in your existing `CombineLatest` in the `SwitchMap` block
- and finally use the result which would now be conversions and username in your `map` block to fetch the username for your return statement

Comment: However, the `userKey` local variable is defined in the `map(conversations =>` block. So basically, I cannot actually use it before it. Do you have any suggestions on how I can deal with that?

Comment: just to understand it more clearly: in your `map(conversations =>` block, you fetch `userkey` with the `switch -> case`. And have this promise code to get user from `userkey` inside the `createConversationObject(..) ` method?

Comment: correct! After fetching the `userKey`, I want to use it in the promise in order to make a new call to the database and retrieve the user's name. After retrieving the name, I want to then pass it to `createConversationObject(..)`.

Comment: cool. so essentially you should do is not call `createConversationObject` in the `map(conversations =>` block since your `createConversationObject ` would be last step in the chain; you should do that at the end. But first you should return the mapped data with the `userkey`. Introduce another `map` block after your existing one and add your promise block converted to an observable returned. You may need to add a `filter` after this in your chain to call `createConversationObject` only when you have the `username` returned by the promise.

Comment: no issues, give me some time, I will probably edit my above answer as per the discussion we had.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176202/discussion-between-akhouri-and-edj).